# Use NavigationButton with a server request in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How can I make a `NavigationButton` to wait for the server response before going to the next view ?

I've tried something like this

```
NavigationButton(destination: LogonView(),  onTrigger: { () -> Bool in
                    return self.viewModel.responseReceived
                }) {
                    Text("OK")
                    }.tapAction {
                        self.viewModel.fetch(companyID: &self.companyID)
                }
```

but the `tapAction` is never called.

I made it working using `Button` :

```
Button(action: {
        self.viewModel.fetch(companyID: &self.companyID)
    }) {
        Text("OK")
    }.presentation(viewModel.shouldPresentModal ? Modal(LogonView() : nil)

    // in ViewModel
    var shouldPresentModal = false { // set to true when data are received from server
            didSet {
                didChange.send(())
            }
        }
```

but I need to show the next view in a navigation, not modally

Thank you!

Comment: I feel like the fact that you're struggling to achieve this means that SwiftUI is not ready enough for it to be used in your app. SwiftUI is in its first beta version and there are lots of things just not ready yet. Just like this... Asking multiple duplicate questions is not going to magically make SwiftUI be able to do something it cannot do.

Comment: Also, that probably isn't the right approach anyway. The next view should display something appropriate based on the state of the model; a spinner while the data isn't present, the data once it is.

Comment: @Fogmeister By now SwiftUI seems to be too "thin" to be used alone, so I think the best approach is using a combination of SwiftUI and UIKit, in my case UINavigationController, now I'm reading about and I'm trying to use UIHostingController, Btw, my last questions cover different issues I found trying to implement my app, they are not "duplicated"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorin, at least in my understanding SwiftUI is designed only for the presentation layer, it's not supposed to replace your model. And it's "reactive", unlike UIKit, so  making the view perform model-like actions is, by design, very hard.

I would approach the task like this :

```
class LoginModel : BindableObject {

    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<LoginModel, Never>()

    private(set) var username: String? {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }

    func load() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
            self.username = "Sorin"
        }
    }
}
```

This is the model object encapsulating our login code. The async operation is here simulated by a simple delay.

And, then, the view :

```
public struct LoginScreen: View {

    @ObjectBinding var loginObject = LoginModel()

    public var body: some View {
        Group {
            if login.username == nil {
                Text("Trying to login, please wait...")
            } else {
                Text("Successful login, the username is \(loginObject.username!)")
            }
        }.onAppear {
            self.loginObject.load()
        }
    }
}
```

There are better ways of "linking" with the model object, but we're looking here only at a bare-bone example, obviously.

Your `NavigationButton` will only link to the LoginScreen, without any other code or trigger.
The screen will initially display `Trying to login, please wait...` and after 5 sec will change to `Successful login, the username is Sorin`. Obviously you could go wild and replace my text here with anything you may want.

Comment: Thanks so much! I've been looking at how to do this for the past 8 hours and here you are with a plain and simple way.  Thanks