# Best-practices to download data from server in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

My question is a conceptual question.

I have the following code:

```swift
struct CategoriesList : View {

    @State private var categories: [CategoryMetadata] = []

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(self.categories) { category in
                NavigationButton(destination: PostsList(category: category)) {
                    CategoryRow(category: category)
                }
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Categorie"))
    }
}
```

That simply compose my UI using a list of elements (categories) and I have a state associated with my view that auto-update the view when it changes.

It's all fancy and nice but for me **it's not clear WHO should fire the network request to fill the model**.

I understood the bindings and the `@state` idea, but, in general, how should I architecture the code to have the models I need at the beginning?

In the old approach I would have implemented this behavior in the `viewDidLoad`, but with the new paradigm of SwiftUI, what is the best approach to get my data?

Comment: It's just UI. You should not request from UI.

Comment: You request from UI all the time, what do you mean?

Comment: Although is not exactly a detail answer to the question and may not be the PERFECT solution, I found this open source project using SwiftUI and Combine frameworks. It's **not** maintained by me, so I cannot guarantee that will be a reference also for the future.

On my opinion this guy has a nice architecture (even if he's using 3rd party library to wrap up the Combine framework, that I *personally* don't like to much) and can be a good starting point to have an overall overview on a project made in SwiftUI/Combine frameworks.

https://github.com/Dimillian/MovieSwiftUI

Answer (score 4):

The SwiftUI community hasn't really established any best-practices yet because the technology is so new. My answer is based off of what I've seen from different WWDC19 sessions.

First, create a `BindableObject` with a `categories` property. Then write your network request code and set `self.categories` to your newly downloaded categories.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

final class CategoryStore: BindableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    var categories = [String]()

    init() {
        // TODO: Fetch categories from API
        self.categories = ["A", "B", "C"]
    }
}
```

Then, add `CategoryStore` to `View` and use it with `List` to iterate over the categories.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    @ObjectBinding private var store = CategoryStore()

    var body: some View {
        List(store.categories.identified(by: \.self)) { category in
            Text(category)
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever the `categories` property updates, your UI will update with the new categories (tysm [Combine](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine))

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56595542/use-navigationbutton-with-a-server-request-in-swiftui/56672982#56672982).

Basically you create a model object conforming to `BindableObject` :

```swift
class LoginModel : BindableObject {

    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<LoginModel, Never>()

    private(set) var username: String? {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }

    func load() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
            self.username = "Sorin"
        }
    }
}
```

This example simulates an async server call by using the plain ol' `asyncAfter`.

Then, the View links with it and it's automatically updated when the model changes.

```swift
public struct LoginScreen: View {

    @ObjectBinding var loginObject = LoginModel()

    public var body: some View {
        Group {
            if login.username == nil {
                Text("Trying to login, please wait...")
            } else {
                Text("Successful login, the username is \(loginObject.username!)")
            }
        }.onAppear {
            self.loginObject.load()
        }
    }
}
```

The key here is to avoid trying to make the `View` perform anything related to the `Model`, except displaying it. `SwiftUI` will resist you all the way :-)

Answer (score 1):

iOS developers don't seem to be as familiar to this idea as Mac OS developers, in Mac apps we split the controller layer into ViewController and ModelControllers, ViewControllers are responsible for synchronise between the views and the model, ModelControllers are responsible for managing archiving of the model etc, so SwiftUI does away with ViewControllers, but if you have network handling then thats where ModelControllers would be useful, they could handle the synchronising between you remote source and you model, this is how I am currently doing it in a sample application I am working, though I have been wondering if Combine could be used to replace that as well, that will be my next thing to experiment with.