# Does Swift UI have a feature akin to viewDidLoad() like UIKit does? If not, how would one create such a function that is called on start up?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, swiftui

When using UIKit, we are able to initialise vars and call functions from the viewDidLoad() function. How is this possible when using Swift UI?

Comment: “we are able to initialise vars and call functions from the viewDidLoad() function. How is this possible when using Swift UI?” What vars and functions did you have in mind? There are none! That’s the whole point.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your response. Take this small example: On startup, I want my application to make a REST call and retrieve the temperature, then I want to set a label's text value to this result. Where would I call the function that would make the REST call? Forgive me if my knowledge is lacking, we all have to start somewhere!

Comment: You would probably use an ObservableObject instantiated as an Environment or ObservedObject property of the root View. But really, if that’s what you want to know, that’s what you should ask.

Comment: Variables are initialized using an init() and .onAppear(perform:) is a good place to kick off something like a refresh of data. I couldn't recommend Apple's tutorial about SwiftUI enough. It's a great place to start your journey.

Comment: you can see this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56690551/best-practices-to-download-data-from-server-in-swiftui

Answer (score 6):

In SwiftUI the lifeCycle methods are:

```
.onAppear {
        print("ContentView appeared!")
    }
```

And:

```
 .onDisappear {
        print("ContentView disappeared!")
    }
```

You can check more details here: 
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-respond-to-view-lifecycle-events-onappear-and-ondisappear